# What do I need to do to enable a user to push with Perforce/Git Fusion OVA?

Tags: virtualbox, git, perforce

I'm using the Git Fusion OVA running in VirtualBox to submodule a Perforce repository into a git repository. I've set up users to be members of the git-fusion-push group, and that group is a subgroup of a group with write access to the depot containing the linked repository.

I've had two users have had their pushes rejected by the pre-receive hook, due to lack of authentication. I managed to reenable one use through various permission changes, while I was trying to work out what was wrong (I made them a superuser temporarily to check that the mechanics was working, which it was - they could then push).

This may or may not be connected to the users trying to push a non-fast-forward commit.

I'm a Perforce beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that the issue was that the users need write access to the .git-fusion depot too (or maybe instead).